# Java erro: cannot find symbol public class

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I created an abstract Kotlin Coroutine Task class but I receive an error when I run app..
Android Studio when I write: extends Corou... it suggests me CoroutineTask<Params, Progress, Result> so it recognized, no syntax errors. Someone could help me? Thanks

> error: cannot find symbol
> public class AsyncCall extends CoroutineTask<String,String,String>{
> ^
> symbol: class CoroutineTask

Coroutine Class file

```
abstract class CoroutineTask<Params, Progress, Result>{


open fun onPreExecute(){}

abstract fun doInBackground(vararg params:Params?): Result

open fun onPostExecute(result: String){}

fun execute(vararg  params: Params?): String {

    var result: String;
    result="";

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
        result = doInBackground(*params).toString();
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main ){
            onPostExecute(result )
        }
    }
    return result;

}}
```

Async Class file

```
public class AsyncCall extends CoroutineTask<String,String,String>{


@Override
public String doInBackground(@Nullable String... strings) {
    return null;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, gradle 4.1 generated error, I changed it to 4.0.1 and now works good!